# Text copy or cut fails with error 0x80004005 in VIsual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

`Type library exporter encountered an error while processing 'CopyAsHtml.CopyAsHtmlPackage, CopyAsHtml'. Error: Type library exporter encountered an error while processing 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsSolutionObject, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop'. Error: Type 'SVsSolutionObject' and type 'SVsSolution' both have the same UUID.`

After that first error dialog, every use of cut or copy produces the E_FAIL, Unspecified Error dialog.

Comment: sounds like a tool bug, you may not get too many responses..

Comment: I searched and found that the error was because of the bug in Power Productivity Tools but the error still prompts after uninstalling it. so can anyone help me to fix it.

Comment: I fear downvotes :). Do a little more research.

Comment: i did but couldnt get the solution so i have posted the question here.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools -> Manage Extensions -> Installed (left top corner) -> Search for CopyAsHtml and disable that extension. This worked for me :)
[image]

Comment: This seems to be the right solution. I faced the same issue, and disabling/uninstalling Copy As Html solved my problem apparently. Though, I'm not sure what other essential operation is deactivated with the disabling of Copy As Html.